# Query Execution Time Varies - IBM Informix - Data Studio

Tags: informix

I am executing one SQL statement in Informix Data Studio 12.1. It takes around 50 to 60 ms for execution(One day date).

```
SELECT  
sum( (esrt.service_price) * (esrt.confirmed_qty +  esrt.pharmacy_confirm_quantity) ) AS net_amount 
FROM
 episode_service_rendered_tbl esrt,
 patient_details_tbl pdt, 
 episode_details_tbl edt, 
 ms_mat_service_header_sp_tbl mmshst 
 WHERE  
esrt.patient_id = pdt.patient_id 
AND edt.patient_id = pdt.patient_id 
AND esrt.episode_id = edt.episode_id 
AND mmshst.material_service_sp_id = esrt.material_service_sp_id 
AND mmshst.bill_heads_id = 1 
AND esrt.delete_flag = 1 
AND esrt.customer_sp_code != '0110000006' 
AND pdt.patient_category_id IN(1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1012,1013) 
AND edt.episode_type ='ipd' 
AND esrt.generated_date BETWEEN '2017-06-04' AND '2017-06-04';
```

When i am trying to execute the same by creating function it takes around 35 to 40 Seconds for execution. 
Please find the code below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION sb_pharmacy_account_summary_report_test1(START_DATE DATE,END_DATE DATE)
RETURNING VARCHAR(100),DECIMAL(10,2);
DEFINE v_sale_credit_amt DECIMAL(10,2);
BEGIN
SELECT   
 sum( (esrt.service_price) * (esrt.confirmed_qty + 
 esrt.pharmacy_confirm_quantity) ) AS net_amount
 INTO 
 v_sale_credit_amt
 FROM 
 episode_service_rendered_tbl esrt,
 patient_details_tbl pdt,
 episode_details_tbl edt,
 ms_mat_service_header_sp_tbl mmshst
 WHERE 
 esrt.patient_id = pdt.patient_id
 AND edt.patient_id = pdt.patient_id
 AND esrt.episode_id = edt.episode_id
 AND mmshst.material_service_sp_id = esrt.material_service_sp_id
 AND mmshst.bill_heads_id = 1
 AND esrt.delete_flag = 1
 AND esrt.customer_sp_code != '0110000006'
 AND pdt.patient_category_id IN(1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1012,1013)
 AND edt.episode_type ='ipd'
 AND esrt.generated_date BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE;
 RETURN 'SALE CREDIT','' with resume;
 RETURN 'IP SB Credit Amount',v_sale_credit_amt;
END
END FUNCTION;
```

Can someone tell me what is the reason for this time variation?

Comment: Look at the query plan for the stored procedure.  Work out why the start date being a constant and the same for both ends of the date range makes such a difference compared to it being flexible and the date range not being constrained to one day.  In the original, the optimizer can convert `AND esrt.generated_date BETWEEN '2017-06-04' AND '2017-06-04'` to `AND esrt.generated_date = '2017-06-04'`.  With the stored procedure, it can't do that.  Do you ever invoke the procedure with different start and end days?  When you run the standalone SQL with a range of days, does it perform as well?

Comment: You may need to look at the indexes on the tables — especially what indexes there are on `esrt.generated_date`.

Answer (score 0):

..in very easy words.

If you create a function the sql is parsed and stored with some optimization stuff in the database. If you call the function, optimizer knows about the sql and execute it. So optimization is done only once, if you create the function.

If you run the SQL, Optimizer parse the sql, optimizes it and then execute it, every time you execute the SQL.
This explains the time difference.

Comment: How can i reduce the execution time from 35 seconds to MS in function?

Comment: In Function Only it takes more time for execution

Comment: Have you indexes on the id fields where you join you're tables?
Have you a index on "generated_date"? I would create a index on this fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the difference in time is due the parametrized query.
The first SQL has hardcoded dates values, the one in the SPL has parameters. That may cause a different query plan (e.g: which index to follow) to be applied to the query in the SPL than the one executed from Data Studio.

You can try getting the query plan (using set explain) from the first SQL and then use directives in the SPL to force the engine to use that same path.

have a look at:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.perf.doc/ids_prf_554.htm

it explains how to use optimizer directives to speed up queries.